# Javascript for loop to add "n" number of option elments?

Tags: javascript, loops, select

I have a number that is generated dynamically, and I would like to add this number of option elements to a select. I am thinking a for loop would be the best way to do this. Say my variable containing the number is var number. thanks for any help.

My starting HTML is:

```html
<select id="test">
    
</select>
```

Using Javascript, I need something like this:

```js
function selectOne() {
    var select = document.getElementById('test');
    // for loop goes here?
    //   e.select[0] = new Option(number);  // do this n times with value also equaling number
}
```

So my resulting HTML needs to look like this, if the number = 6:

```html
<select id="test">  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This builds n options :

```
function selectOne() {
  var select = document.getElementById('test');
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
     select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i);
  } 
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9gKg6/)

Answer (score 2):

This should create your Options. And is backwards compatible for quite-a-many browsers supporting javascript

```
function selectOne() {
    for (var selectEle = document.getElementById("test"), i = 1, o; i <= 6;  i += 1) {
        o = document.createElement("option");
        o.value = i;
        o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        selectEle.appendChild(o);

        /*
        // As pointed out in the comments it can be done as such:
        o = document.createElement("option");
        o.value = o.text = i;
        selectEle.appendChild(o);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: You can actually skip the `appendChild` and `createTextNode`, and just use the `.text` property, so `o.value = o.text = i;` But +1 because I think this probably has better compatibility than the `Option` constructor.

Comment: .text isn't a standard as far as I know. So to keep it as compliant as I could, I chose to just created the elements as above

Comment: Yep, it's DOM Level 1 standard. :) http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-70901257

Comment: Oh well, if nothing else, atleast there's an example of how to create other nodes and such :d

Comment: Sure, perfectly valid solution, and useful elsewhere.